# How can I use a spinner in addition to goroutines so that the output is not overriding each other?

Tags: go

What I am trying to do is use a spinner to indicate work progress in a few goroutines. The issue I am having is that both the spinner message and job completion message is being logged in the same line. What I am asking is how can I have the spinner pinned to the bottom of so that the spinner status is not getting in the way of the logged messages itself?

The output I am getting is

```
a
⡿ 1/26c
⣽ 2/26b
⣯ 3/26e
⢿ 4/26d
⣾ 5/26g
⣟ 6/26f
```

What I am trying to get is

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
⣟ 6/26
```

Temp working code. (I realize my go routines may not be very elegant, but this is just an example).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    "github.com/theckman/yacspin"
)

func main() {
    // create a spinner
    spinner, err := createSpinner()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed to make spinner from config struct: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // start the spinner
    if err := spinner.Start(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    var (
        total   int
        current int
    )

    spinnerCh := make(chan int, 0)
    data := make(chan string)

    // only want one go routine at a time but this is not important
    max := make(chan struct{}, 1)

    go func(s *yacspin.Spinner) {
        // tried moving this into the worker goroutine also, but same effect
        for range spinnerCh {
            current += 1
            if err := s.Pause(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            s.Message(fmt.Sprintf("%d/%d", current, total))
            if err := s.Unpause(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }
    }(spinner)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for d := range data {
            wg.Add(1)
            go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, d string) {
                max <- struct{}{}
                defer func() {
                    <-max
                }()

                // function is doing work and printing the result once done.
                fmt.Println(d)

                // sends a value to the spinner go routine so that it can show
                // the updated count
                time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
                spinnerCh <- 1
                wg.Done()
            }(wg, d)
        }
    }()

    // simulate queing some work
    ss := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
    for _, s := range ss {
        data <- s
    }
    total = len(ss)

    close(data)
    wg.Wait()
    close(spinnerCh)
}

func createSpinner() (*yacspin.Spinner, error) {
    // build the configuration, each field is documented
    cfg := yacspin.Config{
        Frequency: 100 * time.Millisecond,
        CharSet:   yacspin.CharSets[11],
        Suffix:    " ", // puts a least one space between the animating spinner and the Message
        // Message:           "collecting files",
        SuffixAutoColon:   true,
        ColorAll:          true,
        Colors:            []string{"fgYellow"},
        StopCharacter:     "✓",
        StopColors:        []string{"fgGreen"},
        StopMessage:       "done",
        StopFailCharacter: "✗",
        StopFailColors:    []string{"fgRed"},
        StopFailMessage:   "failed",
    }

    s, err := yacspin.New(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to make spinner from struct: %w", err)
    }

    return s, nil
}

func stopOnSignal(spinner *yacspin.Spinner) {
    // ensure we stop the spinner before exiting, otherwise cursor will remain
    // hidden and terminal will require a `reset`
    sigCh := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigCh, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)
    go func() {
        <-sigCh

        spinner.StopFailMessage("interrupted")

        // ignoring error intentionally
        _ = spinner.StopFail()

        os.Exit(0)
    }()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your initial question, here is the solution for not showing the spinner in the lines:

1. Introduce a variable

`pauseItForAMoment := false` which will help to ignore to do Pause or not in one of your goroutine.

```
func main() {
    pauseItForAMoment := false
```

And the goroutine looks like this:

```golang
        // tried moving this into the worker goroutine also, but same effect
        for range spinnerCh {
            current += 1
            if !pauseItForAMoment {
                if err := s.Pause(); err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                s.Message(fmt.Sprintf("%d/%d", current, total))
                if err := s.Unpause(); err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
            }
        }
    }(spinner)
```

2. Stop and Start the spinner while printing `d`

```
                pauseItForAMoment = true
                spinner.Prefix(d)
                spinner.Stop()
                // fmt.Println(d)
                spinner.Start()
                pauseItForAMoment = false
```

3. Change few of the spinner config values to:

```
        StopCharacter:   " ",
        // StopMessage:       "done",
```

Note it, your goroutines are not exactly correct to print them in the order, which you know already, hope you will fix that.

Output looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code if something is not clear https://go.dev/play/p/0lOza3aapf2

I prefer to show the output like this below & the code for that is https://go.dev/play/p/W8Y1kwNqphl (just my 2cents ;-) ignore it if you don't need it)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is not quite what I was after, but set me on the right way. In your case, you are passing `d` to spinner.Prefix, which in my case I cannot do because I am using zerolog for the messages. Also, the counter wasnt working, but I refactored a bit and now it is. https://go.dev/play/p/-7h4v9wK5jO If you have a chance, take a look at the pg. Any suggestions on getting rid of that newline in the output would be helpful! Accepting answer as it showed me what the core problem was.

Comment: @securisec I guess you wanted to remove the empty line in each log entry, and this empty line is generated due to `spinner.Stop()` which uses `spinner.StopCharacter` if you make that `spinner.StopCharacter("")` before `spinner.Stop()` (line 60) then it might print empty line. Ref https://go.dev/play/p/guXSLMTHasN Output: https://i.postimg.cc/CL15vfMy/Screen-Shot-2022-04-18-at-10-13-50-PM.png

Comment: I meant to say "will not print empty line" - instead of "might print empty line".

Answer (score 0):

Author of the library here. Based on the snippet you shared in the [GitHub issue you opened](https://github.com/theckman/yacspin/issues/68), I think you just need to set the `StopCharacter` value to an empty string instead of `" "`. It made it render like this for me...

[image]

Here is [the code](https://go.dev/play/p/sFhKW6oVmyw) on the Go Playground, since I am too dumb to figure out how to copy and paste it here without losing formatting.

I hope this helps!